# Delete files having NOT the same name (incl. different extensions)

Tags: windows, batch

OS: Windows 7

So basically I'm having huge amounts of pictures after a shooting session.
They're automatically saved as `.CR2` file and `.JPG` (so I can preview easier on PC).

Now after deleting all useless `.JPG` files during the preview, there's still a junk of `.CR2` files left which need to be deleted as well.

So my folder looks something like this:

```
IMG_0001.CR2
IMG_0001.JPG
IMG_0002.CR2
IMG_0002.JPG
IMG_0003.CR2
IMG_0004.CR2
IMG_0005.CR2
IMG_0005.JPG
```

As long as the `.JPG` file stays, I want to keep the `.CR2` file as well.
In the example above, I'd need to delete `IMG_0003.CR2` and `IMG_0004.CR2`.

Can you help me out with a range of commands to create a batchfile?

Comment: Order by name and select the CR2 file as well when deleting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd` to the folder and run:

```
forfiles /M *.CR2 /C "cmd /c if not exist @fname.JPG (echo @fname.CR2)"
```

If the results are right then replace `echo` with `del` and run the modified command.

The logic is straightforward: for every `.CR2` file check if the corresponding `.JPG` file exists and delete `.CR2` if not.